# SQL saviong outputs to seperate files

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255)
);
```

The Ouput:

```
**Person ID | Last Name**
100       |  Jones
105       | Davids
109       | Jones Jr
110       | Jones Jr Jr
```

Is it possible that SQL can put the data in sperate CSV files? In this case 2 csv File which contains

CSV File1:

```
**Person ID | Last Name**
105         | Davids
```

and in the other csv 2 file:

```
**Person ID | Last Name**
  100       |  Jones
109         | Jones Jr
110         | Jones Jr Jr
```

Comment: "SQL" is a query language which doesn't know anything about "CSV" or "saving data to files". So "*saving output to a file*" is typically something that your SQL client does.  Which database product and SQL client are you using?  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What rule are you using to separate in 2 CSVs? Why 2? Whay not 3? What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: What is the logic that splits up the result into two results? What is special about person_id 105 that it needs to go into a different file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER

```
$AttachmentPath = "CV File location"
$QueryFmt= "Query"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server -Database DBName -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

If you are using Oracle 12, you can simply type

```
 set markup csv on;
spool C:\DBA\test\file1.csv;
Select * from persons where name like 'David';
spool C:\DBA\test\File2.csv;
Select * from persons where name not like 'David';
```

> Another way is to write a procedure and execute this procedure.